How to transition the overlay SKScene of a SCNView?
I have a SCNView showing an overlay SKView.
I want to transition to another overlay SKView.
let newScene = MyNewSKScene()
let reveal   = SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1)
currentSKScene.view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: reveal)

doesn't work because currentSKScene.view is a SCNView, which doesn't have the presentScene(:transition:) API as SKView has.
Error messae:
-[SCNView presentScene:transition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x136e19dd0

(I checked 0x136e19dd0 is the currentSKScene.view).
Any solution ?

SCNView is just like any other view and can use transition modifier like any view. https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions

Well, that's not what the error message says (see edit of the question)... This is not a SwiftUI SceneView, but a macOS SCNView.
